# Silverlight - Adding MediaElement via C# - short time to manage Play() method

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone, mediaelement

I made simple app in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.
It looks like cell phone keypad with lcd-looks like screen that shows number of current tapped button and plays tone sound of that number.

I've been searching for a while but i found nothing specific.

**I Have problem with Play(); method because it does execute while i'm debugging but in realtime after app-deploy to my device i hear nothing...**

I researched many topics and I can tell that it depends on

```
mediaElementObject.CurrentState;
```

Sometimes it's on "Closed" state and sometimes on "Opening"(and then i hear the sound while debugging).

**C#**

```
private void KeypadButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button currentButton = sender as Button;
        MediaElement keySound = null;
        if (currentButton != null)
        {
            string buttonContentValue = currentButton.Content.ToString();

            keySound = new MediaElement();
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(keySound);
            PlayTargetKeypadSound(buttonContentValue, keySound);
            RefreshNumber(buttonContentValue);
        }
        if (keySound != null)
        {
            ContentPanel.Children.Remove(keySound);
        }
    }

    private void PlayTargetKeypadSound(string buttonContentValue, MediaElement keySound)
    {
        String path = "/Assets/Sounds/keyNumber_" + buttonContentValue + ".wav";
        keySound.CurrentStateChanged += KeySoundOnCurrentStateChanged;
        keySound.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        keySound.Volume = 1.0;
        keySound.AutoPlay = false;
    }

    private void KeySoundOnCurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        MediaElement sound = sender as MediaElement;
        if (sound != null) sound.Play();
    }

    private void RefreshNumber(string buttonContentValue)
    {
        NumberTextBlock.Text = buttonContentValue;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="8,0,8,12">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- First Row -->
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="1" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="2" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="3" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="2" />

        <!-- Second Row -->
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="4" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="5" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="6" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

        <!-- Third Row -->
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="7" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="8" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="9" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />

        <!-- Fourth Row -->
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="*" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="0" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="#" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
```

Many thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I solved it...

**C#**

```
private void KeypadButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button currentButton = sender as Button;
        if (currentButton != null)
        {
            string buttonContentValue = currentButton.Content.ToString();

            PlayTargetKeypadSound(buttonContentValue);
            RefreshNumber(buttonContentValue);
        }
    }

    private void PlayTargetKeypadSound(string buttonContentValue)
    {
        String path = "/Assets/Sounds/keyNumber_" + buttonContentValue + ".wav";
        KeySoundMediaElement.MediaOpened += KeySoundMediaElementOnMediaOpened;
        KeySoundMediaElement.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }

    private void KeySoundMediaElementOnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        MediaElement sound = sender as MediaElement;
        if (sound != null) sound.Play();
    }

    private void RefreshNumber(string buttonContentValue)
    {
        NumberTextBlock.Text = buttonContentValue;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<!-- Fourth Row -->
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="*" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="0" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Click="KeypadButtonClick" Content="#" Style="{StaticResource KeypadButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />

        <MediaElement
            x:Name="KeySoundMediaElement"
            Volume="1"
            AutoPlay="False"
            />
```